# Getting array index out of bound exception after spliting a string

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

After `splitting` a string if last value of index is there then I am not getting any `exception`.

```java
public class Digits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123;456;;;777;000";
        String field[] = s.split(";");
        System.out.println(field.length);
        System.out.println(field[5]);
    }
}
```

**Output is ---> s[5] = 000**

```java
public class Digits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123;456;;;;";
        String field[] = s.split(";");
        System.out.println(field.length);
        System.out.println(field[5]);
    }
}
```

**Output is----> ArrayindexoutofBoundException**

I am expecting `null value` but it is throwing error.

Comment: Why would you expect null? `split()` never returns null elements.

Comment: @shmosel OP expects a blank string `""` at index 5, but the default behaviour of `split()` (without the seconds parameter) is to discard trailing blanks from the split result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you use `String field[] = s.split(";");`, the actual calling method is `split(";",0)`.

```
 public String[] split(String regex) {
    return split(regex, 0); 
 }

 // @param  regex : the delimiting regular expression
 // @param  limit : the result threshold, as described above
 public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    ...
 }
```

when `limit=0` and `the trailing element of the result list is equal to 0`, method `split` constructs the result by removing the empty elements as follows:

```
// Construct result
int resultSize = list.size();
if (limit == 0) {
    while (resultSize > 0 && list.get(resultSize - 1).length() == 0) {
        resultSize--;
    }
}
String[] result = new String[resultSize];
return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
```

This is the reason for `s = "123;456;;;777;000"`  not getting any exception, but `s = "123;456;;;;"` get ArrayindexoutofBoundException.

In conclusion, if you want get "" value, you can assgin `limit = -1 or other inegative number` (Provided you don't want to limit the scope of the `split`), for example:

```
String field[] = s.split(";", -1);
String field[] = s.split(";", -2);
```

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please

Answer (score 1):

If you use the alternative method, it will not throw an error

```
String s = "123;456;;;;";
String field[] = s.split(";", -1);
System.out.println(field.length);
System.out.println(field[5]);
```

As per the single parameter version

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
> array.

However with the 2 parameter version

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible